# File Input failure C++

Tags: c++, file, input, fstream

I've been trying to grasp how reading and writing with the fstream class works, and I've become stuck. The program reads the magic number of the file correctly, and then suddenly fails to read an integer. I'm guessing I am missing something very obvious, but after several Internet searches, I've come up with nothing. If someone could point out what I'm missing, it would be extremely appreciated. Thanks!

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include "File.h"

using namespace std;

const char magicnumber[8] = {'C','H','S','R','L','I','N','E'};
const int magiclength = 8;

void saveLines(char* filename, int linenum, Line* lines){

    //Create the file and write the magic number to it
    ofstream file(filename, std::ios::trunc);
    for(int kkk = 0; kkk < magiclength; kkk++)
        file << magicnumber[kkk];

    //Write the number of lines we expect
    file << linenum;

    //Write the lines' data
    for(int iii = 0; iii < linenum; iii++){
        file << lines[iii].start.x << lines[iii].start.y;
        file << lines[iii].finish.x << lines[iii].finish.y;
        file << lines[iii].thickness;
    }

    cout << linenum << endl;
    file.close();
}

Line* openLines(char* filename){

    ifstream file(filename);
    if(!file.is_open())
        return NULL;

    //Read the magic number of the file
    char testnumber[12];
    for(int jjj = 0; jjj < magiclength; jjj++)
        file >> testnumber[jjj];

    //Make sure the file contains the right magic number
    for(int iii = 0; iii < magiclength; iii++){
        if(testnumber[iii] != magicnumber[iii])
            return NULL;
    }

    //Get the number of lines
    int linenum = -1;
    file >> linenum;
    cout << linenum << endl;
    if(linenum <= 0 || file.fail())
        return NULL;

    Line* product = new Line[linenum];
    for(int kkk = 0; kkk < linenum; kkk++){
        file >> product[kkk].start.x >> product[kkk].start.y;
        file >> product[kkk].finish.x >> product[kkk].finish.y;
        file >> product[kkk].thickness;
    }

    file.close();
    return product;
}
```

In the openLines() function, the file opens correctly, and the magic number is read and matched correctly, but when the variable "linenum" is read, the file reads as gibberish, the fail() flag turns true, and the function returns NULL. If it matters, here's the Line struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int x, y;
} Point;

typedef struct{
    float slope;
    float thickness;
    Point start;
    Point finish;
    bool defined;
} Line;
```

I am using SDL in this project. I do not know if this matters, but I'm including it for completeness' sake. In cout.txt I get 2 (For the linenum when I'm writing the file) and then 2147483647 when I read it back. Thanks for looking!

Comment: What is the contents of the file you write?  I don't see you writing separators/terminators, so it's possible the integer (numLines) you write is getting mixed up with the remaining data.  If you look at the file, you could see what is going on, probably.

Comment: I get exactly what I expected I did. The text file reads:CHSRLINE 3 0 0 600 600 4 40 0 600 0 4 0 80 0 600 4. I inserted the spaces by hand to make sure the numbers were correct, and they are. Also, numlines is the variable right after CHSRLINE, so it's saved to 3. Again, I get 2147483647 when I try to read it again.

Comment: what is lines[] i cant understand because u have not given any info regarding it

Comment: If you're talking about the lines[] in the saveLines() function, it's an array of type Line (see the structs) that is passed in to the function. I've passed three or four lines at a time in to the function, and it writes as I would expect it to. Linenum refers to the amount of lines in the array.

Comment: "I inserted the spaces by hand" - if they are not there, there is no way for the input stream to guess where one integer ends and the next one starts. You must delimit the different fields by whitespace (space, tab, newline).

Comment: Well, I began "Delimiting" the file, but my requirements for the file changed, and I resolved to just create a binary file format to meet my needs. I've figured it out now. Thank you, everyone.